# Passportjs signup works in localhost but doesn't work after deploying in Heroku. Error probably has something to do with cookies

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer, express-session, samesite

I'm using nodemailer to send a random code to the user and then redirecting them to a verify page where they paste the code to verify their account. I'm using mongo Altas.

When I'm running it on localhost it works perfectly but when I deploy to my free version of Heroku the signup page redirects me to the same page as instructed to do for any errors.

**Express-session middleware**

```
app.use(session({
    secret: '9131848995',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection}),
    cookie: { 
        maxAge: 8 * 180 * 60 * 1000,
    }
}));
```

**config/passport.js****

```
    passport.use('local.signup', new localStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, (req, email, password, done) => {
    req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid email').notEmpty().isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Invalid password').notEmpty().isLength({min:6});
    let errors = req.validationErrors();
    if(errors){
        let messages = [];
        errors.forEach((error)=>{
            messages.push(error.msg);
        });
        return done(null, false, req.flash('error', messages))
    }
    User.findOne({'email': email}, (err, user)=> {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        if (user) {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Email is already in use.'});
        }
        transporter.sendMail(Mail(email), (error, info)=>{
            if(!error){
                let newUser = new User();
                newUser.email = email;
                newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(password);
                newUser.v_code = v_code; 
                if (!err) {
                    newUser.save((err, result)=>{
                        if (err) {
                            return done(err);
                        }
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });
                }
            } else {
                return done(null, false, {message: error});
            }
        
        });
    })
}));
```

**Signup route**

```
router.get('/signup', (req, res)=> {
    let messages = req.flash('error');
    res.render('signup', {csrfToken: req.csrfToken(), messages: messages, hasError: messages.length > 0});
});

router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local.signup',{
    successRedirect: '/user/verify',
    failureRedirect: '/user/signup',
    failureFlash: true
}));
```

Thank you.

Comment: Any specific error logs related to the signup process from Heroku?

Comment: Not really seeing anything like that in Heroku Logs. But I saw something about same-site cookies in the console of the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was solved; dotenv caused the issue. Removing the dotenv values and directly putting in the nodemailer auth values solved the problem.

As dotenv FAQ page says,

> **Should I commit my .env file?**
>
> No. We strongly recommend against committing your .env file to version
> control. It should only include environment-specific values such as
> database passwords or API keys. Your production database should have a
> different password than your development database.

Comment: It's nice that you figured the environment variables were causing the problem, however, it is wrong to add environment-specific values in your code, most especially the ones that should be kept secrete. What you should do instead is to store the environment variables in the Heroku environment, there is a guide on how to do that [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).